How does the simple description of spin relate to the Dirac equation?
Coming from a chemistry background, spin (the spin 1/2 case at least) is usually introduced in QM by saying there are abstract $\alpha$ and $\beta$ states together with rules for how operators act on them. Sometimes, the notion of a "spin coordinate" is introduced, so that we can write $\alpha(\omega)$ to make it look more like a usual wavefunction.
While this abstract approach is perfectly ok, I know that spin is usually explained as a relativistic phenomenon with reference to the Dirac equation (at least for electrons). My question then is, how do these abstract $\alpha$ and $\beta$ states come out of the Dirac equation and does the "spin coordinate" have any physical meaning in the more exact theory?

Have you consulted any chemistry or physics textbooks on the topic? Physics textbooks usually spend quite a lot of time discussing the Dirac equation.

WP.

In the OP’s defense, it is extremely hard for a trained chemist to typically understand how physicists define spin since chemists rarely get any training in the representation theory of groups and certainly no training in Lie algebras.

I know that in the non-relativistic limit, one gets the Pauli equation from the Dirac equation, and if I understand correctly, the Pauli 2-component wavefunction is basically a combination of spin-up and spin-down states (so it could be written as $\psi_1 \alpha + \psi_2 \beta$?) However, this still doesn't explain how spin states work for multi-electron systems or what the "spin-coordinate" is.
